# Extreme points of a rather simple function using derivatives

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to find the extreme points of this function with parameters $s,l \in \mathbb{R}$:

$(1):$  $$(\frac{1}{2})^{\dfrac{s}{x}}-(\frac{1}{2})^{\dfrac{l}{x}}$$

I tried doing this by taking the derivative of this function, which is:

$(2):$ $$\frac{\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(l\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\dfrac{l}{x}}-s\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\dfrac{s}{x}}\right)\right)}{x^{2}}$$

From here, I tried setting $(2)$ to be equal to $0$ to find some extreme points of $(1)$.

Equation $(2)$ is equal to $0$ iff:

$(3):$ $$l\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\dfrac{l}{x}} = s\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\dfrac{s}{x}}$$

But taking the ln of both sides of the equation doesn't allow me to find a single value for x, for this gives me:

$(4)$: $$\frac{l\cdot(\dfrac{l}{2})-s\cdot(\dfrac{s}{2})}{x} = 0$$

This seems to settle down the case: there seems to be no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that can satisfy $(4)$.

But this Desmos graph shows this is not the case!
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yn2u9ahhyf

There's a $0$ at $x = 2.31$ for this particular choice of $s, l$. And there exists an $x$ for most choices of $s, l$.

What's wrong with my proof that there is no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that can satisfy $(4)$?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Side question: Does anyone know how can I type the equations in Mathjax so that they don't appear so small? The variables are hardly readable

Comment: About mathjax, either add `$\displaystyle...$` or use `$$...$$` blocks. More tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you! I edited using your advice. The variables in the exponents remain pretty minuscule, though. :P

Comment: For bigger fractions (for example, fractions inside other fractios), use \dfrac instead of \frac.

Answer (score 1):

I love asking questions here, usually it's only after I explain everything in detail here that the mistake becomes apparent. I won't delete this post, however, because it can be useful to someone, I guess.

To get $(4)$, I mistakenly assumed the following:

$ln(ab^{c}) = cln(ab)$.

But this is **wrong**, **subtly wrong**.

The correct way of proceeding from $(3)$ is:

Dividing both sides by $l\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^\frac{s}{x}$ we get:

$(5)$: $$(\frac{1}{2})^\dfrac{l-s}{x} = \frac{s}{l}$$

Taking the natural logarithm from both sides, we get:

$(6)$: $$ \frac{l-s}{x} \cdot \ln(\frac{1}{2})= \ln(\frac{s}{l}) $$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{x}{\ln({\dfrac{s}{l}})}$, we get:

$(7)$: $$ x=\frac{(l-s) \cdot \ln(\dfrac{1}{2})}{\ln(\dfrac{s}{l})} $$

Comment: This is not an answer to your own question. Post it as a comment, please.

Comment: I do believe this is an answer to my own question. My question is: what went wrong with my reasoning? The answer: assuming that equality. I could elaborate on what the extreme points of that function would be, but that's not required by the question. In any case, I will edit my answer to give this value.

Comment: Could you give me a feedback if it's considered an answer to my own question now? I'm new to the forum, and even though I've read the rules, I want to make sure I can be of most benefit. :)